# Unable to find aes-128-encryption key

Tags: c, aes, encryption-symmetric

**I am not able to find any bugs..**

What I want to do:

- read the key(from common word list) from a file
- try all possible key for encryption
- get a key that able to produce preferred ciphertext

Remark:

- encrpytion use AES-128-CBC
- the key has been read that has less 16 characters will be padded with "#"(hex: 0x23)
- wordList is correct

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

void pad(char *s,int length);
int strcicmp(char const *a, char const *b);

int main(){


    int i;

    char words[16],t;
    FILE *key;
    unsigned char outbuf[1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char iv[] = {0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff,0x00,0x99,0x88,0x77,0x66,0x55,0x44,0x33,0x22,0x11};

    int outlen, tmplen;


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    char inText[] = "This is a top secret.";
    char cipherTextGiven[] = "764aa26b55a4da654df6b19e4bce00f4ed05e09346fb0e762583cb7da2ac93a2";
    key = fopen("wordList.txt","r");


    while(fgets(words,16, key)) {

        i=strlen(words);
        words[i-1]='\0';
        i=strlen(words);

        if(i<16){
            pad(words,16);
        }
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(),NULL, words, iv);
        if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inText, strlen(inText))){
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }
        if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf + outlen, &tmplen)){
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }
        outlen += tmplen;

        int i;
        char* buf_str = (char*) malloc (2*outlen + 1);
        char* buf_ptr = buf_str;
        for(i=0;i<outlen;i++)
            buf_ptr += sprintf(buf_ptr, "%02X", outbuf[i]);

        *(buf_ptr + 1) = '\0';

        printf("%s\n",buf_str);
        if(strcicmp(cipherTextGiven, buf_str) == 0){

            printf("Key: %s\nwith corresponding cipher: ", words);
            for(i=0; i < outlen; i++)
                printf("%02x",outbuf[i]);
            printf("\n");

        }

    }
    fclose(key);

    return 1;
}

//provide padding function to key
void pad(char *s,int length){

    int l;
    l = strlen(s);

    while(l<length){
        s[l] = 0x23;
        l++;
    }
    s[l] = '\0'; //add termination char for the array

}

int strcicmp(char const *a, char const *b){

    for(;;a++,b++){
        int d = tolower(*a) - tolower(*b);
        if(d != 0 || !*a)
            return d;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your posting fails to state a question, fails to state what behavior is observed, fails to state what behavior is expected, and fails to give sufficient information to reproduce the problem, notably the contents of “wordList.txt” or at least enough of it to reproduce whatever problem you are seeing. When posting a question like this, you should say whether your program is terminating with no output, is printing wrong output, is crashing with an error message, is not compiling, or whatever, and you should say what output you expect from a working program.

Comment: wordList:
10th
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
a
AAA
AAAS
Aarhus
Aaron
...

Comment: each word occupy one line

Comment: @EricPostpischil: you're right with your comment, but answering such a low quality question sends the wrong message to the OP. Why should he do better if he gets the answer anyway. You can downvote, closevote or at least wait until the OP [edit]s the post to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Errors

Change `char words[16]` to `char words[18]`. You need 18 elements in `words` because you want to handle keys of up to 16 characters, because `fgets` will read a key plus a new-line character, and the buffer will contain a null character after that.

Change `fgets(word,16, key)` to `fgets(word, sizeof word, key)`. `fgets` needs to know the full size of the available buffer, including space for the new-line character and the terminating null character, not just the number of key characters you want.

Delete `*(buf_ptr + 1) = '\0';`. It is unnecessary because `sprintf` writes a terminating null character and because the correct location for it would be `buf_ptr`, not `buf_ptr+1`. So this statement is writing beyond the space allocated for `buf_str`.

### Bad code

The following code is not causing whatever problem you are observing, but it could be written better.

Declare `main` as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, not `int main()`.

Do not write `s[l] = 0x23;` unless you need to write a program that uses a character set different from the character set of the C implementation it is compiled and executed with. To set a character to “#“, use `s[l] = '#';`.

If, in `sprintf(buf_ptr, "%02X", outbuf[i]);`, you change `%02X` to `%02x`, then it will use lowercase for the hexadecimal, and you can use the standard `strcmp` to compare the buffer to `cipherTextGiven` instead of needing a custom `strcicmp` function. Better yet, when the program starts, convert `cipherTextGiven` from hexadecimal to raw binary and, when testing candidate keys, compare that raw binary to the computed cipher text using `memcmp`.

In this:

```
i=strlen(words);
words[i-1]='\0';
i=strlen(words);
```

Change the last line to `i = i-1;`, because we know that the previous line decreased the length by one, so we can set the length directly without calling `strlen` again. Many programmers would write these lines as something like:

```
i = strlen(words);
words[--i] = '\0';
```

Comment: The OP also needs to change the `fgets` size argument.